# Return MongoDB result to an HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, http

I have a NodeJS route that looks like this:

```
app.get("/search/:query", (req, res, next) => {

    let obj = SearchText(req.params.query);

    res.status(200);
    res.json(obj);

});
```

which calls this function:

```
async function SearchText(query) {
    query = "Custom";
    let mongoPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoClient.connect(url,function(err, db) {
          if (err) throw err;
          var dbo = db.db("FunLibsTest");
          dbo.collection("texts").find({"name": { $regex: query }}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
        });
      });
    })

    let results = await mongoPromise;

    return results;
}
```

Expected result is whatever MongoDB finds, but it always returns "FAILED".

I do not believe MongoDB has a synchronous version of "find", but I want it to act synchronously so I can return the response to the HTTP request. How could I do this?

Comment: Why do you have async before the callback of `MongoClient.connect`?

Comment: @gegs921 I tried adding await to the dbo.collection function, but forgot to remove the async after testing. I tried to remove it, but it unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Ok, I think your new problem is a scope problem, I am going to edit my answer to fit this comment, but you should change the callback to an arrow function.

Comment: I edited my answer to put db.close() before the resolve function, I think it wasn't resolving because the db was still open.

Comment: Actually, scratch what I was trying to do before, I edited my answer to give you a more linear solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This code jumps around to a lot of places when we could just make it very linear.

```
function SearchText(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          var dbo = db.db("FunLibsTest");
          dbo.collection("texts").find(query).toArray((err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            db.close();
            resolve(result);
        });
      });
    })
}
```

Then to use the function

```
app.get("/search/:query", (req, res, next) => {

    SearchText(req.params.query).then((results) => {
        res.status(200);
        res.json(results);
    });

});
```

Comment: My query was indeed wrong, so I had to fix that, but it still returns instantly even when using await and async. Quickly after it has returned, the query finishes. It returns "Promise <Pending>" now though, which I guess is progress.

Comment: I edited my answer to solve the problem of "Promise <Pending>"

Comment: Logging the returned value from the function still instantly gives "Promise { <Pending> }", while logging just after "resolve(result);" gives the correct value returned by MongoDB, but only after the function has returned. Nothing makes me rip my hair out more than asynchronous functions.

Comment: I think your problem might be the fact that you have the keyword `async` written before the callback in `Mongo.connect` in your edited answer.

Comment: @AsgeirBjelland what part of the answer helped you? I want to edit the answer so that people that look at this question in the future dont get confused.

Comment: Not sure of the specifics, but making it linear and calling the function with a callback, basically everything after the edit basically, thank you legend.

Comment: Ok. Yw! Also, I'm flattered.